# Why do I get an Error when Creating .text file using php in xampp macOS

Tags: php, html, macos, xampp

I am a Beginner in `PHP` and want to create a text file in my Directory that PHP files are in it but it gives me this Error:

```
Warning: fopen(numbers.dat): Failed to open stream: 
Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Project1/15.filehandling.php on line 13
Error creating the file numbers.dat
```

and my code is =>

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File handling</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    $filename = 'numbers.dat';
    
    $f = fopen($filename, 'wb');
    if (!$f) {
        die('Error creating the file ' . $filename);
    }
    
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        fputs($f, $number);
    }
    fclose($f);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try  $f = fopen($filename, 'w'); or $f = fopen($filename, 'w+');    (from manual : Windows offers a text-mode translation flag ('t')which will transparently translate \n to \r\n when working with the file. In contrast, youcan also use 'b' to force binary mode, which will nottranslate your data. To use these flags, specify either 'b' or 't' as the last characterof the mode parameter. )

Comment: t and b is not a valid mode. 
Permission denied….  

And when trying w+ also the same result permission denied…. I think there should a permission grant in my virtual server or php itself to pass a grant access to hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

we should allow access to our working user to use xampp files with `chmod -R 777 /path of the folder our codes are in it`  or the entire project Directory we work on it.
this is the reason we can't write any things and changes something in virtual server files using IDEs.

Comment: this is tested on macos mojave!!!